# infix operatorが他のファイルから参照できない

Tags: ios, swift

以下のように新たな演算子を定義し、そして処理を書きました。
これをMaybe.swiftとしてxcodeプロジェクトに追加します。

```
infix operator >>= { associativity left }

public func >>=<T, U>(optional: T?, f: T -> U?) -> U? {
    if let x = optional {
        return f(x)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

この状態で、Maybe.swift以外のSwiftコード、例えばViewController.swiftで、

```
let input: String? = "10"
let output = input >>= { value -> Int? in
    Int((value as NSString).intValue)
} >>= { value -> Int? in
    if value >= 0 {
        return value
    }
    return nil
}
```

のように使おうと試みますが、これだけではコンパイルに失敗します。

エラー> [...省略]/ViewController.swift:17:28: Cannot invoke '>>=' with an argument list of type '(String?, $T9)'

トライ＆エラーにより、わかった原因は、演算子の定義が見えていないことです。

なので、この場合、ViewController.swiftのグローバルスコープに、

```
infix operator >>= { associativity left }
```

を足してやることによって、コンパイルに成功し、動作も正常になりました。
しかしこの解決方法では、
この演算子を使いたいファイルには全て

```
infix operator >>= { associativity left }
```

を毎回コピペしなくてはなりません。
これをコピペしなくて済む方法はありませんでしょうか？

Comment: `>>=`は右結合のビットシフト代入演算子とかぶっているので避けた方が良いかもしれません。試してみましたが、`>>==`だと問題ないようなので、ファイル内ではそのファイル内のoperator宣言が優先され、プロジェクト内の他のファイルからは組み込みの`>>=`の宣言が優先されるようです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！

Harawoさん
AppDelegate.swift:11:1: 'UIApplicationMain' attribute cannot be used in a module that contains top-level code
というエラーが増えたこと以外は、変化がなく、エラーが解消されませんでした。

Comment: findallさん
試しに>>==を試しみたところ、確かに改善したのを確認できました！
なるほど、既存の演算子の関係で問題が起こっていたのですね。気づきませんでした。
本当にありがとうございます！

Comment: 最初のコメントを削除してしまいました。まったく役に立たないためです。なお、main.swiftをプロジェクトに追加した場合、AppDelegate.swiftにある「@UIApplicationMain」を削除しなければならないということです。頭の片隅に置いておければさいわいです。

Comment: なるほど、了解致しました。補足ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

次のように括弧を足すとエラーが解消されました。

```
    let input: String? = "10"
    let output = (input >>= { value -> Int? in
        Int((value as NSString).intValue)
        }) >>= { value -> Int? in
            if value >= 0 {
                return value
            }
            return nil
    }
```

必ずしもファイルごとに演算子定義を書かないと使えないというわけではないようです。

(input >>= {}) >>= {}

このように括弧を足すとコンパイルが通りますが、associativity left で定義してるので本来は括弧を書かなくても左から処理されるべきだと思います。
findall さんがおっしゃるように >>== に変更するとコンパイルエラーが解消するので、既存の演算子とぶつかって悪さしてるんじゃないかと思います。

ここらへんはよく分かりませんがXCodeのバグかもしれません。

findall さんと同じ結論ですが、とりあえず >>= は既存の演算子と被るので避けた方が無難かなと思います。

Comment: 仕様なのかバグなのかよくわからない感じですね。Appleのドキュメントも今のところ情報が足りてなくて判断がつかないのが辛いところです

Comment: なるほど、やはり既存とかぶらない方がベターのようですね、ありがとうございます